# Using passport-local with hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to integrate authentication with local passport in hyperledger.
When I use google and GitHub passport it works.But when I tried to use it with local passport it does not work:

```
export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
"local": { 
"provider": "local", 
"module": "passport-local", 
"usernameField": "username", 
"passwordField": "password", 
"authPath": "/auth/local", 
"callbackURL":"/auth/local/callback",
"successRedirect": "/", 
"failureRedirect": "/", 
"setAccessToken": false, 
"callbackHTTPMethod": "post" 
   }
}'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific error that you get when using this, when you try to login via the `composer-rest-server`?

Comment: Hi @VarunAgarwal i have error 404 :    {"error":{"statusCode":404,"name":"Error","message":"Cannot GET /auth/local","status":404,"stack":"Error: Cannot GET /auth/local\n at raiseUrlNotFoundError